# SAS how to create variable with corresponding values efficiently

Tags: arrays, sas

I am trying to complete the following.

Variable Letter has three values (a, b, c). I would like to create a variable Letter_2 with values corresponding to the values of Letter, namely (1, 2, 3).

I know I can do this using three IF Then statements.

```
if Letter='a' then Letter_2='1';
if Letter='b' then Letter_2='2';
if Letter='c' then Letter_2='3';
```

Suppose I have 15 values for the variable Letter, and 15 corresponding values for the replacement. Is there a way to do it efficiently without typing the same If Then statement 15 times?

I am new to SAS. Any clue will be appreciated.

Lisa

Comment: In general I've seen this done with a lookup table or adding/subtracting a constant from ASCII values.

Comment: Do you just want to find where in the list it falls?  Did you look at the `WHICHC()` function? But that would return a number 1,2,3 and not strings '1','2','3'.  However you could use it.

Comment: @Tom In fact, I was trying to assign an order to the values of the variable Letter. So I was trying to create a variable that contains the supposed order of the values Letter and then sort the data using this new variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an application for a FORMAT.

First define the format.

```
proc format ;
  value $lookup 'a'='1' 'b'='2' 'c'='3' ;
run;
```

Then use it to re-code your variable.

```
data want;
  set have;
  letter2 = put(letter,$lookup.);
run;
```

Or perhaps you could use two temporary arrays and the `WHICHC()` function?

```
data have;
  input letter $10. ;
cards;
car
apple
box
;;;;

data want ;
  set have ;
  array from (3) $10 _temporary_ ('apple','box','car');
  array to (3) $10 _temporary_ ('first','second','third');
  if whichc(letter,of from(*)) then 
    letter_2 = to(whichc(letter,of from(*)))
  ;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The Format application is exactly what I need here. And thanks for introducing the whichc() function.