# Create a new column using the look up table

Tags: sas

I have 2 tables

Table 1

```
ID  
122/1
123/2
124/3
127/6
128/8
129/8
```

Table 2

```
id  name 
122/1   R
123/2   P
124/3   J
127/6   Q
```

I need to create a new column in the Table 1 called Name using as a lookup of Table 2 
The table  should look like below

Table 1

```
ID  Name
122/1   R
123/2   P
124/3   J
127/6   Q
128/8
129/8
```

Thanks

Comment: This is going to be marked duplicate... Use a SQL left join, a datastep merge or format. Depending on your dataset size and skillet you can choose a method. You should also post what you've tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAS how to create variable with corresponding values efficiently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34099034/sas-how-to-create-variable-with-corresponding-values-efficiently)

Comment: You only need first two steps in solution above. Or lookup a paper called proc format not just another pretty face.

Comment: Thanks Reeza .. I used Left join to do the requirement. Its fine if I have duplicates also. Thanks for your support